# Android Kotlin PreferenceDataStore

Tags: android, kotlin

```
import android.content.Context;
import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore;

import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.*;
import androidx.datastore.preferences.preferencesDataStore;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow;
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.catch
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map
import java.io.IOException;

public class DataStoreManager {

    // At the top level of your kotlin file:
    val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "setting");
}
```

When generating the "DataStoreManager" class, the following error occurs.
Why?
DataStoreManagerクラスを生成した際に下記でエラーが発生してしまいます。
何故でしょうか？

`val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "setting");`

`AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:Landroidx/datastore/preferences/PreferenceDataStoreDelegateKt;`

It is imported using build.gradle as shown below.
I've been worried about this for a long time and I'm having trouble.
下記の通りbuild.gradleでインポートしております。
長く悩んでいて困っています。

`implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")`

settings.gradle

It didn't work even if I wrote the following
下記を記載してもダメでした

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        **ARTIFACTORYREPOSITORY**
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

include ':launcher', ':unityLibrary'
**INCLUDES**

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        **ARTIFACTORYREPOSITORY**
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs "${project(':unityLibrary').projectDir}/libs"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did ya try to clear the cache? The dependency you're using should contain that classs